# Symfony fixtures getReference Missing reference error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fixtures

I'm new to symfony,
I have Two entities with a ManyToMany relationship.
`Action.php` and `Etablissement.php`
I'm trying to populate my database from two .csv files (one for each object) with doctrine fixtures.

I begin with `EtablissementFixtures.php` in which i reference each `Etablissement` `$this->addReference($line[0], $etablissement);` so that i can access it in my other Fixture.

The problem is that in my second fixture `ActionFixture.php` the .csv contains some id's that don't exist in the `Etablissement`'s .csv. When i try `$this->getReference($line[0])` i get a **Reference to "0010063N" does not exist** error, i've tried to surround the getReference line with a try/catch block but it doesn't work, i want to ignore that error and continue the execution of the code.

I hope that i made it clear, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the SO forums.

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for hasReference function that you can use for checking whether a reference with specific name exists:

```
$this->hasReference($line[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's perfectly what i needed.
It's a bit hard to navigate the symfony documentation, i didn't find it in the DoctrineFixturesBundle page.